# Copying vectors without using the element copy assignment operator - portability

Tags: c++, stl, portability

If I have a type like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    Foo(const Foo&);
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;

    ...
private:
    ...
};
```

And I have two vectors of that type:

```
std::vector<Foo> x;
std::vector<Foo> y;
```

And I want to copy the contents of `x` to `y`, is there a cross-platform way of doing so?

VC++ will do this with `y.assign(x.begin(), x.end())`, which uses `Foo`'s copy constructor instead of the deleted copy assignment operator.  But GCC complains about the missing copy assignment operator, whether you try `y = x` or `y.assign(x.begin(), x.end())`.

Is there some way that will work in both?

Comment: The standard requires that `T` be copy assignable for `std::vector<T>::assign()` to work, even if VC++ incorrectly does not.Can you explain WHY you want class `Foo` to have no assignment operator, but still be able to copy/assign objects of type `std::vector<Foo>`?

Comment: @Peter If `T` has a const member, it can be constructed, but not later assigned. Therefore, it may be reasonable to define a copy constructor, but not a copy assignment operator. Whether this is meaningful (or useful) depends on the application.

Comment: Is there a move constructor and move-assignment operator?

Comment: It's bizarre to have a working copy-constructor but a deleted assignment operator, what is your rationale for doing that?

Comment: It's not done explicitly - the type has const members, which means that by default it has a working copy constructor but a deleted copy assignment operator.  The solution, in the end, is to replace the const public members with private ones and provide const accessors, then replace all references to the members with references to the accessors.

Comment: @Andrew - My question was not about why a class might not have an assignment operator.   I asked why one would want to copy/assign a vector of such objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard requires that for `y.assign(it1, it2)` to work, the element type `T` be *CopyAssignable*. That is, copy constructible and assignable. Your type is not assignable, so you can't rely on `assign`. The same goes for `y = x`. Section 23.2.3 of the standard describes the requirements for various sequence container operations.

If you have an existing vector `y`, you can construct a new vector `z` then swap it with `y`:

```
{
  std::vector<Foo> z(x.begin(), x.end());
  z.swap(y);
}
```

This uses the range constructor, which requires only that `T` be `EmplaceConstructible`, no assignment operator needed! You can then swap the underlying memory without any further copies.

Note that this may result in larger memory usage, since any existing content of `y` will persist until the freshly swapped `z` goes out of scope. You could try to mitigate this by first doing

```
y.clear();
y.shrink_to_fit();
```

although `shrink_to_fit()` is only a request, and may not be honoured by your library implementation.

[[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e63f5d64cbdd09ac)]

Answer (score 3):

Prior to C++11 your code would not have been possible: the vector element type had to be `CopyAssignable`, meaning copy-constructible and assignable.  Note that if the type does not meet these requirements, the code is ill-formed with no diagnostic required; this gives compilers latitude to either accept or reject it.

Since C++11, individual operations have their own requirements. The relevant requirements for `vector` are (source: C++14 Table 100):

- `emplace_back` : `MoveInsertible` and `MoveAssignable`
- `insert`: `CopyInsertable` and `CopyAssignable`
- constructor: `EmplaceConstructible`

The meanings of these traits are (roughly):

- `CopyInsertable`: has copy-constructor
- `MoveInsertable`: has copy-constructor or move-constructor (or both)
- `CopyAssignable`: has copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator
- `MoveAssignable`: `MoveInsertable`, and has copy-assignment or move-assignment operator (or both)
- `EmplaceConstructible`: has constructor

The rationale here is that any insertion may cause a memory reallocation, which *requires* that your objects be able to be either copied or moved. However the Standard does not require the compiler to test whether constructor or assignment operator are each available, and use one if the other isn't. Instead it specifies that both must be available.

---

You didn't specify whether your class is movable. Assuming it isn't, then that means you cannot use any of the emplace or insert methods, nor any other function that might cause reallocation.

If you are creating `y` at the time then you can of course use initialization:

```
vector<int> y = x;
```

If `y` already exists, as your question seems to suggest, then you're nearly out of luck: you can't use any insertion functions, so you can only modify the existing elements. And since there is no assignment operator, you can't do this via assignment.

*But you can use `y.swap()` as suggested in Andrew's answer*.

Consider adding move-constructor and move-assignment to your class, or redesigning your code so that you do not need to assign to `y`. (E.g. use a pointer).

If `x.size() == y.size()` then you can use *placement new* as a last-resort hack:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != y.size(); ++i)
{
    y[i].~Foo();
    new(&y[i]) Foo(x[i]);    // copy-construct
}
```